# FB UI POPUP issue popup blocker in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, google-chrome, fb.ui

When i initiate FB ui pop up block inside ajax it leads to chrome popup blocker

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajaxcheckurl",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data){
        var returnVal=$.parseJSON(data);
        if(returnVal.result==1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                display: 'popup',
                link: 'link',
                name: 'name',
                caption: 'caption',
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response && !response.error_code) {
                } 
                else {
                    }
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    var connectstatus="success";
                }
                else
                {
                } 
                if (response && !response.error_message) {

                } else {                                                
            });
        }
});
```

I need to have fb.ui inside ajax call is there any suggestion for this i have intiate fb.init in document ready but i haven't mentioned it here.

Please give me any suggestion for this.

Comment: Chrome will block it if the user didn't triggered it. Which they didn't do if you do it from an ajax call

Comment: Yes i Understand but i want any solution for it...

Comment: There is no solution. The user needs to trigger it